# Uniform convergence of a series of a cyclic integral

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $\:u_n(x):= \text{sin}(nx)e^{-nx}\:$

Let's also let$$\:\:w_n(y):=\int_{\pi}^{y} u_n(x)\text{d}x$$

Show that the series $$\sum_{n\in\mathbf{N}}w_n(y)$$

converges uniformly for$\:\:y\geq \pi$

I'm quite sure I need to use properties of complex analysis, of wich I'm not too savvy, but I need a head start on that one please =) so that any help'd be appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: Writing $y \geq \pi$ implies $y$ is real, so you're only looking at real arguments to $u_n$ and $w_n$. Look at the Weierstraß $M$-test.

Comment: Can I interchange the summation with the integral?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you must be able to justify the interchange.

Comment: What about "if the summation of $\:u_n(x)\:$converges uniformly then it doesn't matter wich order of sum or integration we choose"

Comment: That works if you use it for $$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} w_n(y) = \int_{\pi}^y \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} u_n(x)\,dx.$$ And it suffices to argue that $\sum w_n$ converges uniformly on every interval $[\pi,R]$ for $R \in [\pi,+\infty)$, but not to show that $\sum w_n$ converges uniformly on $[\pi,+\infty)$ (which it does). For the last, you need something stronger than uniform convergence of $\sum u_n$. A sufficient argument for that would be that $\sum \int_{\pi}^{+\infty} \lvert u_n(x)\rvert\,dx$ converges, for example.